# Adjusting CSS with Chrome Extention

Tags: css, plugins

To increase the usability of a work tool, I'm trying to hide some unused fields with a Chrome plugin and some css edits. The css in question that needs changing:

```
<div class="postProviderProperties">
  <div class="providerPostOption postOption-item">
    <div class="postSidebar-label">
        SomeWords
    </div>
...
```

What I need to do is add a visibility:hidden to the postProviderProperties div class based on the value of SomeWords.

My CSS skills are not great and I'm having trouble figuring out if this is even possible solely with CSS, or am I looking at rolling some js into the plugin too?

None of the CSS antecedent selectors seem appropriate and I do wonder if I'm simply lacking the keyword knowledge to be able to find a good example

Comment: This is not possible with CSS...it can't detect actual **text values**. You need JS

Comment: @ThomasvanBroekhoven Did you not read the question properly? This relates to a CSS injection based on a text value!

Comment: Also, even then this requires a **parent selector** *which does not exist*.

Comment: I like how @ThomasvanBroekhoven deletes his comment. LOL.